# Convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n+\log(1+n^p)}{\sqrt{n-\sin n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n+\log(1+n^p)}{\sqrt{n-\sin n}}$

> A) For which $p\in \mathbb{R}$ is the series convergent?
>
> B) For which $p\in \mathbb{R}$ is the series divergent, and what is the sum?
>
> C) Is the series absolutely convergent for any $p\in \mathbb{R}$?

I don't even know how to start, so far when I had a problem with parameter I could solve by using some tests. But in this case I can't see any tests I would be able to use directly.

Comment: The last one should be easy: The answer is no. (Hint: the absolute value of the $n$th term is asymptotically equal to $p\log(n)/\sqrt{n}$ – or perhaps more easy: greater than $(p\log(n)-1)/\sqrt{n+1}$.) That makes the first two harder, of course. I would suggest bunching the terms into pairs: For $n=2k$ and $n=2k+1$.

Comment: I am sorry my English isn't good. By bunching you mean that I would separately solve for even $n$ and then for odd $n$?

Comment: No, write the sum as $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (x_{2k}+x_{2k+1})$ where $x_n$ is the $n$th term in the original series, then try to get a handle on the size of $x_{2k}+x_{2k+1}$. Because of opposing signs, this should be much smaller than each term alone.

Comment: Oh, wait … I am stupid. Forget what I said about opposing signs. The log term in the numerator beats the $(-1)^n$ term of course! So the whole problem is a lot easier than it looks. It's a trap, and I fell right into it. But … if $p\le0$ then it might still be difficult. Perhaps you can use my suggestion in those cases.

Comment: Yes, @AndréNicolas has it right. I spouted an amazing amount of nonsense above, but there should be nuggets of good advice in between. Sorry about that, I'll go have breakfast now.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Can you clarify a bit? I don't think I understand your hint. thank you

Comment: I was sloppy. We have obvious divergence if $p$ is positive, but other values need work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A-B) For $p\leq0$
 $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n+\log(1+n^p)}{\sqrt{n-\sin n}}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n-\sin n}}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\log(1+n^p)}{\sqrt{n-\sin n}}\ , $$
the first term converges by Leibniz criterion and the second term can be written as
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\log(1+n^p)}{\sqrt{n-\sin n}}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n^p+O(n^{2p})}{\sqrt{n-\sin n}}\ ,$$
which conveges for $p<-\frac{1}{2}$ and diverges for $-\frac{1}{2}\leq p\leq0$.

For $p>0$ the numerator is positive so the series has only positive terms:
you obtain divergence by comparison criterion
$$\frac{(-1)^n+\log(1+n^p)}{\sqrt{n-\sin n}}\geq \frac{\log(1+n^p)-1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\geq \frac{C}{\sqrt{n+1}}\ .$$
C) Absolute convergence never occurs since for any $p$
$$ \left|\frac{(-1)^n+\log(1+n^p)}{\sqrt{n-\sin n}}\right| $$
has a subsequence whose sum is divergent i.e.
$$\frac{1+\log(1+(2n)^p)}{\sqrt{2n-\sin 2n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-\sin 2n}}+\frac{\log(1+(2n)^p)}{\sqrt{2n-\sin 2n}}\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-\sin 2n}}\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}\ .$$

Comment: thank you, now that you break it down like this everything makes sense :).

Comment: For $p \le 0$, you cannot apply Liebniz criterion because the magnitude of the terms is not monotonic. In fact, $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n-\sin n}}$ converges while the part $\sum \frac{\log(1+n^p)}{\sqrt{n-\sin n}}$ diverges for $p \ge -\frac12$ and converges if $p < -\frac12$.

Comment: Take for example $p=0$: at the numerator you have $(-1)^n+\log2$: for even $n$ is positive, for odd $n$ is negative: the sum is alternating and its absolute value goes as $n^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, which is infinitesimal...

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{10^6}\frac{(-1)^n+\log 2}{\sqrt{n-\sin n}} \sim 436.6740488464859$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{10^7}\frac{(-1)^n+\log 2}{\sqrt{n-\sin n}} \sim 1384.581810581359$. This isn't a good sign for the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n+\log 2}{\sqrt{n-\sin n}}$ to converge. Even without absolute converge, you can continue to split a sequence into two provided at least one of them is converging.

Comment: You are right...

Comment: @achillehui: I edited the answer: thanks for your comments.

Comment: @Dario Can you explain what is $O(n^{2p})$?

Comment: When you expand $\log(1+x)$ for $x$ close to 0 you get $\log(1+x)= x+O(x^2)$ that means that the first term of the expansion is x ($\log(1+x)$ behave as $x$ near 0) and the other terms in the expansion are of the order of $x^2$. Basically is simply an estimate of the error you do approximating $\log(1+x)$ with $x$. In this case you have $x=n^p$ (which is small only for negative $p$).

Comment: It now looks much better but one still cannot apply Leibniz criterion to the first term. The only way I can show $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n-\sin(n)}}$ converges is split it once more as $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} + \sum \left( \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n-\sin n}} - \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$. The first term is now in a form one can apply Leibniz criterion and the second term converges absolutely.

Comment: @achillehui why is not possible to use Leibniz criterion for $\sum (-1)^n \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{n-\sin n}}$? If I calculated properly I got that $\lim \frac{1}{\sqrt{n-\sin n}} = 0$ and $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-\sin n}})'<0$ so the sequence is non-increasing

Comment: @D.N. Oh. you are right, the $n-\sin n$ is indeed monotonic, one can apply Leibniz criterion in this case.

Comment: +1 Since D.N has cleared my last concern, this is definitely an answer that worths an upvote.

Comment: Thanks to everybody for the comments